# clang 7 does not have std::map::merge?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++

When I use std::map's merge(source) I got an error:

```
error: no member named 'merge'
```

However, the `std::map::merge` should be there since c++17.
I do add `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` and `-stdlib=libc++`. The std::map::extract is already there. Is this a bug in clang-7?

If I get rid of `-stdlib=libc++`, the gcc header does contain std::map::merge. Then I can compile. But I do need `-stdlib=libc++` for my project. Any idea?

I dig around and find out that the merge neither exists in `llvm/include/c++/v1/map` nor in `llvm/include/c++/v1/experimental/map`. So which header should I include for that? Or the c++17 support in clang-7 is still problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in LLVM 8 but not 7. It's item p0083r3 in [the C++17 status table](http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html), and here's the commit:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/5c4e07ae5c6f7f467b436f1b24f41ef4cf9897b3

From the tag list it doesn't look like it's been back-ported to 7.

Comment: Ooops ... bad news